# Getting info about the last workflow run for a specific ID in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I'm confused, is there any way to get the status of the last workflow run for a specific workflow ID via the API? I don't see a way to do this after reading the REST API documentation on GitHub Actions.

Elaborating, my `.github/workflows/` folder in my repository looks like this:

```
.github/
 |_ workflows/
     |_ deploystaging.yml
     |_ deployprod.yml
```

Both of these have `on-push` trigger, so they start building as soon as any commit is pushed.

Now, I want to get info (whether success or fail) about the `deploystaging.yml` file explicitly via the REST API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs) to list all workflow runs given a workflow id. Every run object contains `status` with the current run status and `completion` with the result of the build (tells you if it succeeded or failed).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually now in `conclusion` instead of `completion`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).